# fast retrieval of lua objects from C/C++

Tags: c++, c, lua

All non-local `lua` objects are stored in some table. Retrieving objects from a table usually means a hash calculation of a key is made first and then the corresponding object retrieved. I'd like to avoid the extra step of hash calculation.

The easiest thing (as was once possible) would be:

```
lua_Object o(...some lua call...);
lua_pushobject(o);
```

But, as mentioned, this is not possible anymore. So, how can I store and then push a `lua` object (specifically, a large table, that would be slow to recreate) onto the `lua` stack quickly? I know about the registry, but that is just another table, the hash calculation is not avoided, if I store/retrieve from there.

EDIT:

Some details:

One of the well-known problems of `lua` wrapper libraries is the temporary table problem. Say I call:

```
control:camera():get_something_else()
```

Where `control` is a table (wrapped C++ object) with  CFunctions. The method `camera` will return a table (another wrapped C++ object) each time it is called. It would be nice, if we could cache this table, so it would not need to be recreated each time, as time is critical (we use C/C++ for performance reasons). Also we don't want to look the table up from another table, as this implies the calculation of the hash of some key (say the instance of the wrapped C++ object cast to an integer), as well as other look up costs. I am aiming at the latest `lua` version 5.2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but perhaps you want `lua_pushvalue`?

Comment: @lhf Could be, but how to store a table at an index, that is independent of the stack?

Comment: Have you measured the performance impact of storing the object in the registry (using, e.g., [`luaL_ref`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_ref))?

Comment: The hash codes for a string is computed just once, when the string is created. To access `t.k`, `k` is not rehashed, but it is looked up in `t`.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew I did something similar. I traced into `lua` code and saw it calculated a hash of any key I supplied, or searched linearly. `luaL_ref` is just a utility function from `auxlib`. It thinks up a "unique" integer and stores a value under that integer key into the registry. I not only want to avoid hash calculations, but all lookups in general for the sake of fast temporary table creation.

Comment: @lhf There is still some look up cost, but I didn't look into it closely. There's still some look up loop.

Comment: Use integers as keys starting from `1` and keep them consecutive so there are no "holes" in the table. From the C++ side, use `lua_rawgeti` so you avoid a meta lookup. This should guarantee array-like lookup in the table without needing to compute the hash.

Comment: This concern strikes me as premature micro-optimization. All of Lua depends on tables, and performance of tables is tuned carefully. The internal "array part" of a table is one example, integer keys landing in the "array part" are accessed without hashing. Strings are interned, and as a side effect their hash is known, making `t.k` access more efficient. The `rawget` access form is also available to bypass any possible metamethods. All that said, without careful benchmarking that shows that this is your bottleneck, you are likely worrying needlessly.

Comment: @RBerteig For some applications you are undoubtedly right. But even a whiff of a loop makes me panic while writing a C++ wrapper.

Comment: @user1095108, I understand but I recommend getting things to work and measuring performance before hunting problems that may not exist. There are a *lot* of performance-critical things written in Lua that move data between the Lua stack and the C API. If wrapping at this level is a problem, then you might consider LuaJIT and its FFI feature (not in core Lua) that allows calls in and out of the C side without creation of CFunctions and marshalling through the Lua stack.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem with an upvalue into which the result of a CFunction can be cached; this includes a table. The CFunction can check whether a non-nil value already exists in the upvalue. If so, it can merely reuse the existing (up)value. Access to the upvalue does not involve any lengthy look ups. I won't accept this answer, since I've originally asked the question and would like to encourage other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, hash is not being calculated while pushing and object. Table is rehashed when adding or removing it's elements

Look at [`lobject.h`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lobject.c.html):

```
#define setobj(L,obj1,obj2) \
 { const TValue *o2=(obj2); TValue *o1=(obj1); \
   o1->value = o2->value; o1->tt=o2->tt; \
     checkliveness(G(L),o1); }
```

If You had filled `Table` object ([`lobject.h`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lobject.h.html)) You could easily copy them and populate different Lua Virtual Machines with those. Macros ( from same [`lobject.h`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lobject.h.html) for setting `TValue`'s value to Your `Table`:

```
#define sethvalue(L,obj,x) \
  { TValue *i_o=(obj); \
    i_o->value.gc=cast(GCObject *, (x)); i_o->tt=LUA_TTABLE; \
      checkliveness(G(L),i_o); }
```

Only thing... You're going to leave borders of public Lua C Api waaay behind... :)

You might need to check the [`ltable.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/ltable.c.html) and [`lstate.h`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lstate.h.html) too. Maybe will try to craft a proper code example later...

EDIT:
also, if You'd like to significantly decrease rehash count, use [`lua_createtable(lua_State *L, int narr, int nrec);`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_createtable) instead... :)

Comment: hash is calculated when I access a stored table. Say, I push the table somewhere (into the registry). Then I want to push it onto the stack later. To do that I need to access it with a key and a hash of the key will be calculated when I do that.

Comment: @user1095108
Could You please be more specific about Lua version? I might misunderstood what actually would You like to do. So, some code or pseudo-code example might help a lot. Thanks ^_^